# Why am I unable to restart or shutdown my computer from the LightDM login screen?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, lightdm, restart

I'm not sure whether this is a bug (in which case I'll submit a report) or I'm doing something silly!

My problem is that I cannot restart or shutdown my computer from the LightDM login screen, this problem occurs if I go through the following steps:

- Log in
- Lock the screen either through inactivity or selecting "lock screen"
- At the password entry screen select "Switch User"
- Click the power symbol at the top right of the LightDM login screen and select "restart" or "shutdown"

When I do this nothing happens, the computer does not restart or shutdown and neither is there any error messages, I would have assumed that if I'm not supposed to be able to select these options then I'd at least get a warning message?

So does anyone know if this is a bug or something dumb I'm doing!?

I filled a bug-report on launchpad for this a while ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/932724

Comment: I have the exact same trouble. The impact is only effective after some time of use (logged into unity and used unity). If I ask to shutdown or restart soon after starting the computer it does shutdown or restart. I use unity-2d. If someone has the solution please post it here. Maybe this bug is the start of the trouble : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/899830 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792 Best regards.

Comment: @AntoineRodriguez Neither of those bug reports sound quite like this problem, IMO.

Comment: It's a known bug and has been around for a long time.  Hopefully this will sometime become addressed.  The only workaround that I know of is to log back in then try to shutdown.  Unfortunately even that doesn't always work.  The only way I have been able to successfully shutdown Ubuntu using a GUI is to install Cairo-dock.  Others are suggesting to use a terminal screen and run `sudo shutdown -r now`  or `sudo shutdown -h now` for reboot or shutdown.  You can get to a terminal console by hitting `alt-ctl-F1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already logged into another user account, then try to restart or shut down without logging out of all accounts first, the machine may prevent shutdown from occurring in order to protect the possible loss of those users' data. I agree it should offer a dialog with some explanation, however.

You should try [filing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/18612) that thoroughly describes the current behavior and how to reproduce it, as well as what you might have expected to happen instead. (You can easily do this if you have a Launchpad account by running `ubuntu-bug lightdm` in the terminal.)

Also, don't forget to edit a link to the bug back into your question so future visitors can locate it easily and mark themselves as affected.